# What are some online courses on artificial general intelligence?

Tags: agi, reference-request

Although no artificial general intelligence (AGI) has yet been created, probably, there are already some courses on the topic. So, what are some online (preferably free) courses on AGI?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, no AGI system has yet been created, so that's why there aren't yet many courses on AGI. However, there are a few courses that attempt to address AGI as the main topic but from different perspectives. Below, I will mention the ones that I found and partially followed, and give some info about them.

#### [MIT 6.S099: Artificial General Intelligence](https://agi.mit.edu/)

This is organized by [Lex Fridman](https://lexfridman.com/). It is a series of lessons and talks primarily given by a diverse set of guest appearances, such as

- [Josh Tenenbaum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ROelYvo8f0) (researcher and professor in computational cognitive science),
- [Nate Derbinsky](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfO4EkoGh40) (who gives a lesson on cognitive architectures, Soar, etc.),
- [Stephen Wolfram](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7kX7BuHSFI) (creator of Mathematica, Wolfram Alpha and the Wolfram Language; he talks about his work throughout the years, especially, the development of Wolfram Alpha and Language),
- [Marc Raibert](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiNSPRKHyvo) (CEO of Boston Dynamics, who gives a lesson on his work at Boston Dynamics and the robots they have developed),
- [Lisa Feldman Barrett](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwsft6tmvBA) (professor of psychology, who gives a very insightful lesson on emotions and feelings, with possibly different perspectives),
- [Rosalind Picard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kq0VO1FqE6I) (a professor at MIT, director of the Affective Computing Research Group at the MIT Media Lab, and co-founder of two companies, Affectiva and Empatica; in her talk with Lex, she talks about affective computing and other interesting concepts and issues)
- [Marcus Hutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1AxVXt2Gv4) (inventor of a mathematical theory of general intelligence, AIXI; in his talk with Lex, he talks about Occam's razor, Solomonoff induction, Kolmogorov complexity, the definition of intelligence, AIXI, rewards, bounded rationality and consciousness)

#### [Knowledge-Based AI: Cognitive Systems](https://www.udacity.com/course/knowledge-based-ai-cognitive-systems--ud409)

It's taught by Ashok Goel and David Joyner. As the name of the courses suggests, this course focuses on knowledge-based AI.

#### [The Society of Mind](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-868j-the-society-of-mind-fall-2011/video-lectures/lecture-1-introduction/)

This course is taught by Marvin Minsky, who had also written [a book and developed a theory of natural intelligence with the same name](http://www.acad.bg/ebook/ml/Society%20of%20Mind.pdf).

#### [CS 294-149: Safety and Control for Artificial General Intelligence (Fall 2018)](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs294-149/fa18/)

I don't think that there are (free) recorded video lectures, but, in the [lecture schedule](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs294-149/fa18/#lecture-schedule) section of the course, you have links to references that they use during the course (e.g. [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.06565.pdf)), which seems to focus on safety and control aspects of future AGI systems. See also [these notes](https://github.com/HumanCompatibleAI/cs294-149-fa18-notes).

#### [General Theory of General Intelligence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8nzFqoEOvE&list=PLAJnaovHtaFTK9E1xHnBWZeKtAOhonqH5&index=2&ab_channel=SingularityNET)

This is not really a course, but it's a series of videos by Ben Goertzel, who summarises some of the topics presented in [a paper that the same Ben Goertzel wrote about AGI](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.15100).